# How to send the WWW-Authenticate header using Keycloak using LDAP Kerberos

Tags: ldap, keycloak, kerberos

As per the Keycloak manual, the Kerberos authentication flow should be like:
https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/#configuring-a-kerberos-storage-provider

```
A typical use case for web authentication is the following:

1. User logs into his desktop (Such as a Windows machine in Active Directory domain or Linux machine with Kerberos integration enabled).

2. User then uses his browser (IE/Firefox/Chrome) to access a web application secured by Keycloak.

3. Application redirects to Keycloak login.

4. Keycloak renders HTML login screen together with status 401 and HTTP header WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate
...
```

However, I'm not getting the WWW-Authenticate header after sending the login. What I'm getting is a 302 (Redirect) to the Realm but with no header !!

[image: Keycloak-Kerberos-login]

Please note the following:

- Keycloak

  1 - User Federation LDAP configuration in Keycloak works correctly, I can login and sync the LDAP users.

  2 - Kerberos integration is set and the keytab file works correctly since I can do LDAP search from the console

[image]

3 - In the Keycloak Authentication flow Kerberos is enabled and required.

- Client

  1 - I had added the server URL to the Internet sites.

If you have any idea why the [WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate] header is not being sent I'll appreciate it.

Comment: The header should appear on the `/auth` resource, you only show the /login request. Could you verify there is no header on the `/auth` request ? Could you share your auth flow configuration ?